# SQL Server Full Text Search With Join Doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Running Full text search query with CONTAINS predicate runs successfully when done against a single table (simple query)

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Entity] A 
WHERE CONTAINS(A.EntityName,'Test')
```

This query returns multiple results matching the CONTAINS predicate.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Entity] A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityLink] B
ON A.Id = B.EntityId
```

This query also returns multiple results with EntityName that Contains the phrase Test in it.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Entity] A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityLink] B
ON A.Id = B.EntityId
WHERE CONTAINS(A.EntityName,'Test')
```

**This query doesn't return any results**. *(I have just added the contains predicate to the second query)*.
I've tried multiple options, and I'm a bit frustrated since it's not behaving as expected.
Why does a join prevent it from working properly?

Comment: Could you add sample data returned by your second query (the one with `JOIN` but without `CONTAINS`) specifically those rows which contain the word `Test`?

Answer (score 0):

See if the version with [CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql) returns any data:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Entity] A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityLink] B
ON A.Id = B.EntityId
JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Entity], [EntityName], 'Test') as FTS
ON FTS.[KEY] = A.Id
```

`CONTAINSTABLE` is specifically intended to be used in `JOINs`. However, to be 100% precise we need to see the data returned by the query with `JOIN` as per my comment above.

Comment: This actually run but still doesn't work as expected. Example with CONTAINSTABLE:
SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE([Entity], [EntityName], 'Test') -> Return succesfully all the entityNames that equal to Test. However if you change CONTAINSTABLE to CONTAINSTABLE([Entity], [EntityName], 'Te') it doesn't return any result (although there are more than 10 entity names that starts with Te)

Comment: @MasterOfPuppets you probably want to use predicate search. In this case, it should be `'"te*'"`